# Search for table td title

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, search

I will explain what I'm doing, I'm calling Facebook API and getting: Profile picture, Name and ID, and I append profile picture to table td, the name as title, and ID is hidden, also having a checkbox so my users can select who they want.

I would like to search trough a table, but search for the title, that attribute is not displayed on html it self or at least visible, so other search methods I have found, doesn't seem apply here.

Here is the appending table code:

```
function (data) {
    var mytable =document.createElement('table');
    mytable.setAttribute('id','FBTable');
    var tr=document.createElement('tr');
    var rowCounter = 0;
    for( var i = 0; i < data.data.length; i++ ){
        rowCounter++;
        if(rowCounter == 8){
            var tr=document.createElement('tr');
            rowCounter = 0;
        }
        var image = document.createElement('img');
        image.src = data.data[i].picture.data.url;
        image.style.height=100 + 'px';
        image.style.width=100 + 'px';
        var td=document.createElement('td');
        var input=document.createElement('input');
        input.setAttribute('type', 'checkbox');
        input.setAttribute('AddEventLisener', 'checkbox');

        input.setAttribute('class', 'InputClass');
        input.setAttribute('id','' + i) ; // the + '' is for converting the number i to string .
        td.setAttribute('class','TdClass')    ;
        td.setAttribute('title',data.data[i].name );
        td.setAttribute('id', data.data[i].id );
        td.appendChild(input);
        td.appendChild(image);
        tr.appendChild(td) ;
        mytable.appendChild(tr);
    }
    $('article.FriendsList').append(mytable);
```

I thinking datatable might be a good solution, but this code is used a lot in the project, so if there is a better way to use it now.. will be great, thanks ahead.

Comment: is there a reason you cannot use a css selector like `var allTitleTD = document.querySelectorAll("td[title]");` and then simply run through those?

Comment: I haven't seem no search methods that use it, or have any example on how.
so I might, but I haven't seen one or know how, redirections if there is, will be appricated